# Irreducible complex characters of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group.

If $\chi$ is a complex character of $G$, we define $\overline{\chi}:G \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\overline{\chi}(g)=\overline{\chi(g)}$ for all $g \in G$. We write

$\nu(\chi):= \frac{1}{|G|}\displaystyle\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g^2)$

for the Frobenius Schur Indicator.

We let Irr($G$) denote the set of irreducible complex characters of $G$. We want to show that:

$\displaystyle\sum_{\chi\in Irr(G)}\nu(\chi)\chi(1)=|\{h \in G:h^2=1\}| (1)$

We define $\alpha:G \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\alpha(g)=|\{h \in G: h^2 = g\}|$, which is a class function. Thus we can write $\alpha$ as

$\alpha=\displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(g)}\langle\alpha,\chi\rangle\chi $, which follows from the fact that $\alpha$ is a class function and $Irr(G)$ is an orthonormal basis of the
vector space $R(G)$ of class functions of $G$. We can see that equivalently what we want to show is that

$\displaystyle\sum_{\chi\in Irr(G)}\nu(\chi)\chi(1)=\alpha(1)$.

We have

\begin{split}
\alpha(g) &= \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \langle \alpha(g),\chi(g) \rangle \chi(g)\\
&= \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \frac{1}{|G|} \displaystyle \sum_{g \in G} \alpha(g) \overline{\chi(g)}\chi(g)
\end{split}

Also

\begin{split}
\displaystyle\sum_{\chi\in Irr(G)}\nu(\chi)\chi(1) &= \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \frac{1}{|G|} \displaystyle \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g^2)\chi(1)\\
&= \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \langle \chi(g^2),\chi(1) \rangle
\end{split}
but I am really not sure where I should go from there to show that $(1)$ is true. I'd appreciate some hints.

Comment: How is this question different from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182388/question-on-irreducible-complex-characters ?

Comment: In the question you linked I was also asking for some clarification on showing that $\alpha$ is indeed a class function. Having that clarified, I thought I'd ask another less dense question because I thought that asking one question other than two in one post may simply be easier for someone to read it and to know what's going on.

Comment: Perhaps you may have some hints at hand?

Comment: Your calculation of $\alpha(g)$ is wrong. You should not be evaluating $\alpha$ and $\chi$ in anything inside the inner product, and you should end up with two different variables in which to evaluate when you write out the inner product.

Comment: Thank you! So what you're saying is that I should somehow expand $\alpha = \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \langle \alpha , \chi \rangle \chi$ and then I can evaluate $\alpha$ and $\chi$, is that correct? I'm not sure how to do that tho, if that's the case..

Comment: So you noted that you need to evaluate $\alpha(1)$. set $g=1$ in your calculation of $\alpha(g)$ and fix the errors I mentioned. Then see what you get.

Comment: So I'd get $\alpha(1)= \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \langle \alpha(1), \chi(1) \rangle \chi(1) = \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \langle \alpha(1) , \chi^{2}(1) \rangle$. I think I can do that since $\chi(1)$ is just a constant ?

Comment: No, you did not fix the error I pointed out.

Comment: $\alpha(1) = \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \langle \alpha,\chi \rangle \chi(1) = \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \langle \alpha,\chi \chi(1)  \rangle $?

Comment: It should've been (I think) $\alpha(1) = \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \langle \alpha,\chi \rangle \chi(1) = \displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \langle \alpha,\chi(1)\chi   \rangle =\displaystyle \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \frac{1}{|G|} \displaystyle \sum_{g \in G} \alpha(g) \chi(1) \overline{\chi(g)} $?

Comment: Yes, that is correct now. You might consider switching the order in the inner product to get rid of the complex conjugate given that it is symmetric and $\alpha$ is real, but that is a minor thing. Now to figure out whether this leads where you need to go...

Comment: Yeah, it looks like $\alpha(g)\overline{\chi(g)}$ should be equal to $\chi(g^2)$? But I have no clue how one should go about showing this...

Comment: Do you have any ideas?