# Product of a class function with a conjugate of an irreducible character

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

Let $\chi$ be an irreducible complex character of a finite group $G$ and define $f:G \to \mathbb{C}$ by $f(g)=|\{h \in G:h^2=g\}|$. From a question which I am trying to solve it appears that $f(g)\overline{\chi(g)}=\chi(g^2)$, but I have no idea how one should go about showing that this is actually true (assuming that it is indeed correct). Any ideas?

Comment: This appears to be false for a cyclic group. Are you sure you aren't missing like a summation or something?

Comment: Well actually,  I want to show that $\frac{1}{|G|}\displaystyle \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g^2) = \frac{1}{|G|}\displaystyle \sum_{g \in G} f(g)\overline{\chi(g)}$ and it seems like I very naively assumed that it was enough to show that the expression inside the sums were equal in order to show that the above sums are also equal...

Comment: Still not sure how I could tackle that tho. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: $f$ is a class function so it is a sum of characters multiplied by a constant. With $\rho$ the regular representation then $f(g) =\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{x \in G} tr(\rho(gx^{-2}))$. But in general
$x \mapsto x^2$ isn't an homomorphism so $x \mapsto \rho(x^2)$ isn't a representation and that doesn't tell us of which characters $f$ is a sum. Same problem with your $\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g^2)$. Possibly to construct the representation such that $f =\alpha\ tr(\pi)$ we'll want to use Brauer induction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @reuns, I've never encountered this (Brauer induction) before, but I'll look at it. Here is the question to which the above is related to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183421/irreducible-complex-characters-of-a-finite-group. Maybe, by not showing you the whole context, I am over complicating this question..

Comment: What [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator) is explaining : for any representation $\pi$ let $i_\pi= \sum_{x\in G} \pi(x^2)$. Then $\pi \mapsto \pi i_\pi$ is an interwinning because $\pi(g) i_\pi = \pi^{-1}(g^{-1}) i_{\pi^{-1}}= \sum_{x\in G} \pi^{-1}(g^{-1} x^2)=\sum_{x\in G} \pi(x^{-2}g)=i_\pi \pi(g)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $S$ of pairs $(a,b) \in G\times G$ satisfying $a^2 = b$.  Now consider the expression:

$$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{(a,b) \in S} \chi(b) $$

On the one hand we could just sum over the first coordinate and since each $a$ value appears with exactly one such $b$ this is just:

$$ \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{a\in G} \chi(a^2)$$

On the other hand we could sum over the second coordinate, this time the different $b$ values occur different numbers of times, but this number of times is just $f(b)$ by definition. Therefore we get:

$$ \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{b\in G} f(b)\chi(b)$$

Therefore:

$$ \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{a\in G} \chi(a^2) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{b\in G} f(b)\chi(b)$$

But wait that's not what you wanted! You wanted the $\overline{\chi(b)}$ on the right hand side, how can this be?

Well notice that $f(b)$ is a real function so

$$\overline{\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{b\in G} f(b)\chi(b)} = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{b\in G} f(b)\overline{\chi(b)}$$

But $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{b\in G} f(b)\chi(b)$ is rational as it is a rational virtual character multiplicity (in fact it is 0,1, or -1 but that's a story for another time) so it's equal to its own conjugate.

Comment: Yeah , I know that the lhs  of the second last equation is a Frobenius Schur Indicator so it is 0,1 or -1 and so the last bit with complex conjugates etc. follows. That is very, very nice @Nate, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For any representation $\pi: G\to GL(V)$ of a finite group [let](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator) $$i_\pi = \sum_{x \in G} \pi(x)$$

Then $i_\pi = i_{\pi^{-1}}$ and $\pi(g) = \pi^{-1}(g^{-1})$ so $$\pi(g)i_\pi = \pi^{-1}(g^{-1}) i_{\pi^{-1}} = \sum_{x \in G} \pi^{-1}(g^{-1})\pi^{-1}(x^2)= \sum_{x \in G} \pi^{-1}(g^{-1}x^2)=\sum_{x \in G} \pi(x^{-2}g)=i_\pi \pi(g)$$

Thus $\pi|_{i_\pi V}$ is a representation $G \to GL(i_\pi V)$.

With $\pi$ the regular representation then $tr(\pi(g)) = |G| 1_{g = 1}$ and

the basis of $i_\pi V$ are the different cosets $y G^2 \in G/G^2$.

$G$ acts by permutation on those and $tr(\pi(g)|_{i_\pi V}) =\sum_{yG^2, gyG^2=yG^2}1$.

For $V$ a $k$-vector space with $char(k) \nmid |G|$, decomposing the regular representation in a sum of irreducible representations $\pi = \sum_j \rho_j$ then $\pi i_\pi = \sum_j \rho_j i_{\rho_j}$ where $\rho_j|_{i_{\rho_j}}$, being a subrepresentation of $\rho_j$, is $0$ or $\rho_j$.